# "round" time_t to day/hour?

Tags: c, time

I have a unix time_t , is there any easy way to convert this to a time_t so it:

1. Represents midnight of the day of the time_t ?
2. Represents the start of the hour of the time_t ?

Comment: what does midnight of the day mean?(its _always_ at 00:00), and what does start of the hour mean?(its _always_ xx in xx:00)

Comment: @Ankinet Afaik, yes, midnight is at 00:00, and I've never seen a start of an hour that's not xx:00.

Comment: @uesr949760 so what is the question then? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Aniket It's as the question states. Lets take a specific example, I have a time_t with the value 1359769961 . That is is 2013-02-02 02:51:41. How to (mathematically) convert this to e.g. 1359766800 (2013-02-02 02:00:00) and to 1359759600 (2013-02-02 00:00:00)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
time_t t = time(NULL);

t -= (t % 86400);
```

The constant 86400 = 24 * 60 * 60 - a useful number to remember, I think... ;)

Answer (score 3):

Let the computer remember the celestial constants for you:

```
time_t      arg, start_of_hour, start_of_day;
struct tm   *temp;

temp = localtime(&arg);
temp->tm_sec  = 0;
temp->tm_min  = 0;
start_of_hour = mktime(temp);
temp->tm_hour = 0;
start_of_day  = mktime(temp);
```

Or use `gmtime` if you prefer.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no portable inverse for `gmtime`.